# Saving Images Causing OutOfMemory Exception 2nd Time Around

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
    Private Shared Values(4) As Integer
    Private Shared myImage As Bitmap
    Private Shared myArea As Rectangle
    Private Shared ocrImg As Bitmap
    Private Shared ImgCpy As Bitmap

    Public Shared Function PrepImage(ByVal filename As String, ByVal savename As String, ByVal filetype As String) As Boolean
        '// Grab region of image for processing
        Try

            Select Case filetype
                Case "A"
                    Values(0) = 2240
                    Values(1) = 255
                    Values(2) = 40
                    Values(3) = 150
                    Values(4) = 3
                Case "B"
                    Values(0) = 184
                    Values(1) = 255
                    Values(2) = 85
                    Values(3) = 20
                    Values(4) = 0
                Case "C"
                    Values(0) = 933
                    Values(1) = 755
                    Values(2) = 270
                    Values(3) = 62
                    Values(4) = 0
                Case Else
                    Return False
            End Select

            myImage = Bitmap.FromFile(filename)
            ImgCpy = New Bitmap(myImage)
            myImage.Dispose()
            myArea = New Rectangle(Values(0), Values(1), Values(2), Values(3))
            ocrImg = GetPicturePart(ImgCpy, myArea)
            ocrImg.RotateFlip(Values(4))
            ocrImg.Save(savename, Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
            ocrImg.Dispose()
            ImgCpy.Dispose()
```

This function works the first time i call it, but subsequent times it fails, sometimes i seem to get a parameter not specified exception, but mostly i get a out of memory error. Do i have to set the image to Nothing at the end as well, i thought Dispose would release all the resources they are using?

I refactored the code as follows but still having issues, this does not use the get picturepart function, but here it is as well...

```
Private Shared Function GetPicturePart(ByVal SourceImage As Image, ByVal Region As Rectangle) As Bitmap
        Dim ImagePart As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Region.Width, Region.Height)
        Using G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(ImagePart)
            Dim TargetRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, Region.Width, Region.Height)
            Dim SourceRect As Rectangle = Region
            G.DrawImage(SourceImage, TargetRect, SourceRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        End Using
        Return ImagePart
    End Function

 Dim myImg As New Bitmap(filename)
            Dim MyArea As New Rectangle(Values(0), Values(1), Values(2), Values(3))
            Dim myFormat As PixelFormat = myImg.PixelFormat
            Dim myOCR As Bitmap = myImg.Clone(MyArea, myFormat)
            myImg.Dispose()
            myImg = Nothing
            myOCR.RotateFlip(Values(4))
            myOCR.Save(savename, Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
            myOCR.Dispose()
            myOCR = Nothing
```

Comment: You should be make Bitmaps on the fly so they are only in the Sub's scope.

Comment: I refactored the code see above

Comment: What does GetPicturePart do? oh.. I guess return a new image? Should probably add that in here.. to the code so we can see

Comment: Is it bad to be putting 5 values in Values(4)?  Also `myImage.Dispose()` begs to be followed by setting myImage to Nil or Empty or something.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong.. even if you were leaking the bitmaps completely (which you're not) you should be able to create many more than 2 of them.. I'm think you must, therefore, be passing something incorrect into the constructor of a bitmap. Either an invalid file, incorrect dimensions, etc. What line is failing with OOM?

Comment: It works fine the first time, the 2nd time i hit it, it now gives me a "Parameter is not valid." I trace it back to the line Dim myImg As New Bitmap(filename); however filename shows the correct file path, and i can very that the file exists. SHould i try using a stream to read the file in? Maybe it cant get an exclusive lock on the file and that is causing the issue?

Comment: @danh What about ebyrob's comment VB.NET isn't my thing, but that looks fishy.. you'd think that would cause an obvious exception though

Comment: @danh Are you sure the file is a valid image? How big is it? Have you tried other image files?

Comment: `Dim myImg As New Bitmap(filename);` opening the same file twice perhaps?  That's a really common problem in this kind of scenario.

Comment: @ebyrob reasonable guess, but wouldn't it be closed after creation of the bitmap and surely after .Dispose?

Comment: This is not unusual, bitmaps can require a *lot* of memory.  And you'll easily run out of a hole in the virtual memory address space to fit the pixel data if the next image is larger than the previous one.  A 64-bit operating system and changing the Target CPU setting on your EXE project to AnyCPU is a very simple workaround.

Comment: @Alan .Dispose() would definitely do it assuming... well a lot of things, I need to read more of this.  (I'm a C# guy too)

Comment: Quite often, especially when dealing with the GDI, when you get an `OutOfMemoryException`, it's because you have run out of GDI object handles.  Each process is limited to 10,000 simultaneous GDI objects.  It's a limitation of the operating system.  It may not even be a fault of this particular code.  It could be that all the handles are being used up elsewhere, *before* this method is called.  Add the **GDI Objects** column to your windows task manager and step through the code and see if that is hitting 10,000.

Comment: @ebyrob In VB.NET, the `n` in `Dim a(n) As Integer` specifies the last index, not the number of elements.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks, wow right there in the example.

Comment: @danh You should take out the `whatever = Nothing` statements. They do nothing useful as you have already disposed of the objects. Have you tried the code you show in a minimal program to make sure that there isn't something else pushing it over the edge? And made sure that the files you are using are not corrupt?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses guys. Here is what i was able to determine:

Changing the code seems to the 2nd one i posted seemed to eliminate the out of memory errors. Just less steps in the code, and disposing of the images right after use and setting them to nothing.

The parameter is incorrect issue while vague was actually because something else had a lock on the file so the process was able to load it. My best guess since i was copy and pasting from a test folder into the production capture folder, the system would grab the file quicker then the system would be able to complete the operation, or maybe since windows try's to generate thumbs it was trying to do it, im not sure.

In either case, i sleep the thread for a few seconds before attempting the image operations and i have not been able to reproduce either errors.....